# Ruby: overwrite line in file

Tags: ruby, file-io

I am trying to log some state to a file using standard file i/o in ruby. The file will just have one line with a number in it. I want to read in the line and then on each iteration of a loop I want to update this number.

I know I can read in the file with

```
file = File.open('out.log', 'a+')
num = file.readline
```

The problem is, I don't know how to then overwrite the first line in a loop without just re-opening the file every iteration i.e.

```
file = File.open('out.log', 'w')
```

which will create an empty file

Comment: You must look into the lib [Logger](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#class-Logger-label-Example) while writing logs. This is a standard way to do this job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to open it each time:

```
file = File.open('out.log', File::RDWR)
10.times do |i|
    file.seek(0) # rewind to the beginning of the file (line in your case)
    file.write("iteration #{i}") # write what you want

    # the following is just in order to show what was written
    file.seek(0)
    puts file.readline
end
file.close
```

Comment: Please don't rely on any other resources to close your file.

Comment: Of course you're absolutely right, I didn't put it here but that was implicit in my mind. Anyway I'll update the code.

Comment: Why `file.seek(0)` at the beginning ?

Comment: for the subsequent loop iteration. we could put it at the end of the loop (but that's less readability IMO). If we remove it altogether then the writing step will append the text at the end of the existing content instead of replacing it.

Comment: Humm.. I understood. Tried something differ based on your code. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IO::open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/IO.html#method-c-open) with block to close the file, when block exits automatically.

```
File.open("#{__dir__}/test.txt", File::RDWR) do |file|
  10.times do |i|
    file.rewind
    file.puts("iteration #{i}")
  end
end

puts File.read("#{__dir__}/test.txt")
# >> iteration 9
```